# How to use GestureHandler?

Tags: interactive, eventhandler

Gesture handlers would be *really cool to have*. There is a symbol called [GestureHandler](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GestureHandler.html).  It's eight years old (from v9) but intriguing to me, as I could never ever get it to work.

***Does anyone know how to use it?***

[image]

The docs state that `GestureHandler` works for standard gestures: "Pinch", "Drag", "Spin", "Tap", "LongPress". But needless to say, the above never prints "Pinched!". The details section states:

> that `GestureHandler` is only active on touchscreen devices and
>   otherwise acts as an inert wrapper"...

But rather vaguely doesn't mention which touchscreen devices are supported, and in what wolfram (desktop, mobile, cloud...)?

**What I've tried:**

I've got nothing from any of the following approaches when running the ref page examples in v12.0 on:

- Recent macs: iMac, Mac Pro, Macbooks Air/Pro
- Recent touchscreen Windows and Linux machines
- Recent iPad, iPhones, and Android devices with the Wolfram Cloud and CDF Player apps
- Deploying Wolfram Cloud notebooks/pages and accessing them from the above-mentioned devices

Comment: `GestureHandler` is currently only supported on iOS devices.  Specifically, the Wolfram Player app.

Comment: But laptop touchpads support those gestures as well, why not support MacBooks?

Comment: Put simply, user demand.  You should definitely submit your interest as feedback.